# Access control in other window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, controls

This my first question, so bear with me if I don't explain everything as thoroughly as I should - thanks in advance!

I'm working on an app that's a sort of database, and I'd like to have my information viewable in the main window.  However, when someone goes to add a new piece of information, I'd like to create a new label in the original window that lists the data-point.

For example, if you have the mainWindow, and the 'input a new datapoint window' (dataInputWin), you type your datapoint (data1)in the dataInputWin and hit enter, and it adds a label to mainWindow with contents (data1).

I'm a beginner in WPF, and my biggest problem here is accessing the StackPanel or grid in a different window so that I can input/create a new label.

Comment: I would suggest you look at databinding. You can bind two UI controls to a common dataset which if you perform an update on one control it will  update the view on the other control. It allows you to cleanly monitor and update objects between views without having to couple.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464965.aspx

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will certainly look into that!

Comment: @muglio Thanks, but I don't think that really answered the question I intended to ask - I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to do something like this: mainWindow.stackPanel1.children.add(data1).  So basically, I can't figure out the code for how to access a different window's controls, or if this is even possible.  If there is a better way, I'd appreciate it if someone let me know.

Comment: You absolutely can. When you open up your dataInputWin you can set the MainWindow or pass in a specific user control. You just need to add a property to dataInputWin. Ex: public MainWindow OtherWindow {get;set;} You can do it but you absolutely shouldn't do it this way. See:  [Tight Coupling...](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212515/why-is-tight-coupling-between-functions-and-data-bad) What I am recommending is that with databinding you can share a poco between the two Windows and databind to that poco. Or implement the observer pattern between the two windows.

Comment: Be aware that this is possible but it is considered a bad design. You'll get hopelessly lost when you scale this up. The real answer is the MVVM pattern, but in any case: do not use controls as data-store. Their function is to display things.

Comment: I would recomend to share `DataContext` between the two windows, and make sure that the collection is either `ObservableCollection` in your `ViewModel` or use the `CollectionViewSource` in your `View`s. Anyhow @HenkHolterman is right do not do `WinForms` in `WPF` or you will get stuck.

Comment: @muglio and everyone else since it's telling me that only one user can be notified, thanks a ton for the help, I'll certainly look into those ideas.